# Распознование аудио (не речи) в python

Tags: python, аудио

Есть такая ситуация: на компьютере запущена игра, и из нее идут различные звуки: выстрелы, сирены и т.д. Нужно, чтоб программа прослушивала аудио из этой игры и реагировала на какой-то определенный звук. Есть ли какие-то библиотеки для этих целей в Python 3 ?
Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет. Сомневаюсь, что это возможно. Если из своей игры на Питоне, то тогда можно изменить сам подход. А иначе, нет.

Comment: Ват? Перехватить звук это вообще не проблема(разве что возможно придеться писать что-то на с++), далее распознать одинаковые звуки тоже. Что невозможного то?

Comment: Вы сами написали что: "возможно придется писать что-то на с++". По этому в контексте "Есть ли какие-то библиотеки для этих целей в Python 3" ответ == нет.